# jQuery call PHP method ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, methods

How would I call a PHP Method/function from jQuery ajax. Is this even possible? If it is not possible in jquery, is it possible in plain javascript? I have searched the web trying to find the answer but no site I could find was helpful. Would I need to make an ajax request to another php file, set a session variable dedicated to this and then make the other ajax request and in the requested php file, use the session data to perform the operation of am I over thinking this? Thanks for any help possible!

Comment: Yes you are over thinking this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

very simply,
**jquery:**

```
$.get("code.php");
```

**PHP:**

```
<?php func(); ?>
```

**for advanced:**
use this jquery to run php:

```
$.get("code.php?action=func1");
```

and write this code in php:

```
<?php
if( $_REQUEST['action'] == 'func1' ){
   func1();
   die();
}
?>
```

Comment: yes, you can change PHP code to this: <?php classname::functionname() ?>

Answer (score 7):

An AJAX call is the same as loading the URL in your browser.  So, you need to make a way to have your PHP script call the right function based on the URL, such as `$_GET` variables.

For example:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_GET['func'])){
       $func = $_GET['func'];
       if($func === 'a') a();
       if($func === 'b') b();
    }
```

Then make an AJAX call to: `http://example.com/script.php?func=a`.

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://example.com/script.php',
    type: 'GET',
    data: {func: 'a'},
    success: function(data){
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

Comment: there is a comma missing after `data: {func: 'a'}`